# GCloud Compute Engine to local Hyper-V stuck on localhost login

Tags: linux, ssh, hyper-v, gcloud

I'm trying to get my GCE server off the cloud and onto a local virtual machine. I've been able to successfully get the server image into the correct format using [this guide](https://linuxnovice.com/how-to-export-google-cloud-engine-vm-to-local-laptop-or-pc-step-by-step/) however I can't figure out how to sign in.

Starting up the VM shows `localhost login` while when connecting from the GCE Dashboard it simply uses SSH. Account passwords aren't working here, I had reset the passwords before downloading the image.

What are my options here? I thought I could SSH in but I'm not sure how to find the IP of the Hyper-V and don't know how the SSH key situation will work -- it's currently managed via GCE Meta Data.

**-- UPDATE --**

I set a static MAC address

[image]

Added a DHCP reservation

[image]

Ensured that the Network Adapter is using the wireless card

[image]
[image]

However, the VM does not seem to have an IP

[image]

Could it be that there's some setting within the GCE image that is preventing it from being found on the network?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

While still running in GCE, confirm the ssh key you want is in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. When [python Linux guest environment for GCE](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/tree/master/packages/python-google-compute-engine) is installed, this probably already exists if you ever logged in with gcloud. (I don't think the users are removed when the metadata service isn't there. But if so, create different named users.)

Give the guest known names and IPs. Set a static MAC address, a DHCP reservation with a known IP, and DNS records with this IP. ssh to this name.

Comment: I was able to set a static MAC address and a DHCP reservation. I'm not sure what it means to set a DNS record with this IP, shouldn't I then just be able to do: `ssh USERNAME@LOCAL_IP`?  I did try this and the connection timed out.

Comment: It is fundamental to put every host in DNS, or at least the local hosts file. Anyway, find the IP address (console to the VM or trace ARP / NDP / DHCP), and start debugging why you cannot connect.

Comment: Seems the router says the device with that MAC address is offline. Going to start by playing with the network adapter settings of the VM... IP address should be what I reserved in DHCP shouldn't it?

Comment: I updated the question with the additional information I've tried. Seem to be having troubles with the network adapters, not sure what to do next.